# Union of two queries

Tags: sql-server, union

I'm trying to union two queries as follows (the alias is one of my attempts to resolve the issue);

```
SELECT a.Day, a.[Away Days], a.[Office Days] 
FROM (SELECT DATENAME(dw, Date) AS 'Day', SUM(Hours)/8 AS 'Away Days', NULL AS 'Office Days' 
    FROM  TimesheetDays 
    WHERE id_LineItem IN 
        (SELECT idLineItem FROM TimesheetLineItems 
        WHERE id_Timesheet IN 
            (SELECT idTimesheet 
            FROM Timesheets 
            WHERE id_User = 314) 
        AND id_Leave IS NOT NULL AND id_Leave != 4)
    AND Date < GETDATE()
    GROUP BY DATENAME(dw,Date)) a

UNION

SELECT b.Day, b.[Away Days], b.[Office Days] 
FROM (SELECT DATENAME(dw, Date) AS 'Day', NULL AS 'Away Days', SUM(Hours)/8 AS 'Office Days' 
    FROM TimesheetDays 
    WHERE id_LineItem IN 
        (SELECT idLineItem FROM TimesheetLineItems 
        WHERE id_Timesheet IN 
            (SELECT idTimesheet 
            FROM Timesheets 
            WHERE id_User = 314) 
        AND Offshore = 0 AND (id_Leave IS NULL OR id_Leave != 4))
    AND Date < GETDATE()
    GROUP BY DATENAME(dw,Date)) b
```

The problem is that this isn't doing a proper union. I'm wondering if it's maybe the Group By part that's wrecking things, but I don't think so?

This is a sample result;

```
Day         Away Days   Office Days
Friday      NULL        23.0125
Friday      7           NULL
Monday      NULL        24
Monday      6           NULL
Thursday    NULL        26
Thursday    5.5         NULL
Tuesday     NULL        25.9375
Tuesday     7.5         NULL
Wednesday   NULL        26.05
Wednesday   8           NULL
```

What I'm looking for is both values to be on the same line, rather than having NULL's and I'm not quite sure why this is happening (an explanation as well as a solution would be greatly appreciated).

I'd like to keep the aliases as I'm thinking it would be nice to add a 4th column with the ratio and potentially other things too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two and use the same logic.

```
SELECT a.Day, ISNULL(a.[Away Days],b.[Away Days]) as [Away Days], ISNULL(a.[Office Days],b.[Office Days]) as [Office Days] 
FROM (SELECT DATENAME(dw, Date) AS 'Day', SUM(Hours)/8 AS 'Away Days', NULL AS 'Office Days' 
    FROM  TimesheetDays 
    WHERE id_LineItem IN 
        (SELECT idLineItem FROM TimesheetLineItems 
        WHERE id_Timesheet IN 
            (SELECT idTimesheet 
            FROM Timesheets 
            WHERE id_User = 314) 
        AND id_Leave IS NOT NULL AND id_Leave != 4)
    AND Date < GETDATE()
    GROUP BY DATENAME(dw,Date)) a

JOIN   (SELECT DATENAME(dw, Date) AS 'Day', NULL AS 'Away Days', SUM(Hours)/8 AS 'Office Days' 
    FROM TimesheetDays 
    WHERE id_LineItem IN 
        (SELECT idLineItem FROM TimesheetLineItems 
        WHERE id_Timesheet IN 
            (SELECT idTimesheet 
            FROM Timesheets 
            WHERE id_User = 314) 
        AND Offshore = 0 AND (id_Leave IS NULL OR id_Leave != 4))
    AND Date < GETDATE()
    GROUP BY DATENAME(dw,Date)) b ON a.Day = b.Day
```

Answer (score 0):

If one query selects Away Days, the other Office Days, why not simply JOIN the two instead of UNIONing them? Write them as two derived tables and link them in the outer query perhaps? Outline:

```
SELECT
  a.day,
  a.[Away Days],
  b.[Office Days]
FROM
  ( Q1 ) AS a
  INNER JOIN ( Q2 ) AS b ON
    a.day=b.day
```

Answer (score 0):

This is behaving as expected. A union will not do a merge of the fields, but give you a combined set from n selects.

You might want to consider a join instead

Answer (score 0):

Use [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) to get your desired output

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw, Date) AS 'Day',
       (CASE WHEN (id_Leave IS NOT NULL AND id_Leave != 4) THEN SUM(Hours)/8
            ELSE NULL
       END)
        AS 'Away Days', 
       (CASE WHEN (Offshore = 0 AND (id_Leave IS NULL OR id_Leave != 4)) THEN SUM(Hours)/8
            ELSE NULL
       END)
       AS 'Office Days' 
    FROM TimesheetDays 
    WHERE id_LineItem IN 
        (SELECT idLineItem FROM TimesheetLineItems 
        WHERE id_Timesheet IN 
            (SELECT idTimesheet 
            FROM Timesheets 
            WHERE id_User = 314))
    AND Date < GETDATE()
    GROUP BY DATENAME(dw,Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats the need for UNOIN, check the below query and hope this works for you:

```
SELECT a.Day, a.[Away Days], a.[Office Days] 
FROM (SELECT DATENAME(dw, Date) AS 'Day', SUM(Hours)/8 AS 'Away Days', SUM(Hours)/8 AS 'Office Days' 
    FROM  TimesheetDays 
    WHERE id_LineItem IN 
        (SELECT idLineItem FROM TimesheetLineItems 
        WHERE id_Timesheet IN 
            (SELECT idTimesheet 
            FROM Timesheets 
            WHERE id_User = 314) AND Offshore = 0 
        AND id_Leave IS NOT NULL AND id_Leave != 4)
    AND Date < GETDATE()
    GROUP BY DATENAME(dw,Date)) a
```